# Should Cache-Control request headers influence server-side caching?

Tags: http, caching

A have seen a lot of discussion regarding proxies with regard to [RFC7234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234) and the Cache-Control header, but I'm not too clear on whether the request headers should impact server-side caching or not.

The diagram below shows where the headers I am concerned are located (down arrows are request headers, up arrows are response headers):

```
      ┌────────┐
      │ Client │
      └────────┘
        ↓    ↑
      ┌────────┐
      │ Cache  │
      └────────┘
        ↓    ↑
      ┌────────┐
      │ Cache  │
      └────────┘
        ↓    ↑
      ┌────────┐
      │ Server │
      └────────┘
  ??? → ↓    ↑
    ┌─────────────┐
    │ Server-side │
    │    Cache    │
    └─────────────┘
```

I have a number of questions regarding the interaction between Cache-Control and server-side caching (e.g. should `Cache-Control: no-cache`, mean that the server should re-validate its own cache?). But the vast majority boil down to the following:

**Should the server-side use Cache-Control and other associated headers from the request for logic regarding its server-side caches?**

Take the following small (albeit crude) Python Flask application as an example:

```py
@app.route('/app/<id>')
def endpoint(id):
    if 'no-store' not in request.headers['Cache-Control']:
        # If 'no-store' isn't specified, try cache first
        entry = entry_cache.get(id)
        if entry is None:
            entry = service.get_entry(id)
    else:
        # Otherwise, immediately talk to the service
        entry = service.get_entry(id)
    return entry
```

In addition, this raises another question which, depending on the answer, may render the above irrelevant:

**What kind of caching should be done on the server-side? What situations should we rely on HTTP caching and calculate the response on each request (outside of situations like `If-None-Match`)?**

For context, most applications I tend to develop are designed as micro-services either as containers or as serverless functions with caches tending to be calls to external services such as Redis. Not many browsers call these HTTP endpoints; most clients are business applications.

**Update (2021-08-17)**: Thanks Kevin for the feedback! I have updated the diagram and some of the wording to clarify that I refer specifically to the request caching headers rather than the response headers. In addition, I've added a very small (and *very* crude) Python Flask app to help illustrate the type of logic I am referring to.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks for the response! I've updated the description to include some better examples. Even then, I think you have brushed against the crux of the question: are the request headers for `Cache-Control` only intended for proxies? If so, I was never aware of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP caching specification is not binding on the internal caching behavior of the server. The server's response is, by definition, fresh, regardless of how it was generated. So while it would be a violation of the protocol for an intermediate proxy to serve a cached response to a request with a `no-cache` directive, it wouldn't be for the server itself.

That said, it's certainly possible to harmonize both kinds of caching, whether implicitly (in response to requests that happen to have caching request headers set) or explicitly (defining your API to use HTTP caching headers for internal behavior). So your Flask example makes a lot of sense to me. That said, I'm not familiar with sites or frameworks that use these request headers outside of caching proxies, so you may be a trailblazer in this regard.